# How to generate multivariate Normal distribution from a standard normal value?

Tags: python, random, random-seed

I need to generate multivariate Normal distribution using only a generator of a random value and without scipy or numpy generators.

I need to generate the following
[image]

This is my attempt

```py
V = np.array([
    [1, 2], 
    [2, 5]])
B = np.linalg.cholesky(V)
A = np.array([1,2])

# norm() return one number from standard normal distribution 
n1 = np.array([norm() for _ in range(40)])
n2 = np.array([norm() for _ in range(40)])
np.array([n1,n2]).T.dot(B) + A
```

Here, I used Cholesky decomposition as [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1344788/cholesky-decomposition-and-variance)

However, I reckon this is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, but you can check that your numbers don't have the desired covariance property, if you apply [numpy's `cov`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html) function:

```py
res = np.array([n1,n2]).T.dot(B) + A
np.cov(res.T).round()
# returns ~ 
# array([[5., 2.],
#        [2., 1.]])
```

Note that the elements 1,1 and 2,2 are exchanged compared to the desired value.

To leverage numpy's CPU-vectorized matrix multiplication, you use [numpy's `dot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html?highlight=dot#numpy.dot) function. You properly arranged the N pieces of 2D input vectors Z into a Nx2 dimensional vector `np.array([n1,n2]).T`. But as you pointed out in the [Cholesky decomposition and variance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1344788/cholesky-decomposition-and-variance) question, the Z values have to be multiplied by B from the left, and you also would like to incorporate it into the `dot` function's broadcasting rule, and the problem lies here. The code `np.array([n1,n2]).T.dot(B)` multiplies the (array of) Z from the right, not from the left. To compute the left-product by B, you need to use `dot(B.T)`

This example also shows that the covariance matrix has the right form

```py
import random
import numpy as np

random.seed(0)
N=10000

V = np.array([
    [1, 2],
    [2, 5]])
B = np.linalg.cholesky(V)
A = np.array([1, 2])

# norm() return one number from standard normal distribution
n1 = np.array([random.gauss(0, 1) for _ in range(10000)])
n2 = np.array([random.gauss(0, 1) for _ in range(10000)])
res = np.array([n1, n2]).T.dot(B.T) + A

np.cov(res.T).round()
# returns ~  array([[1., 2.],
#                   [2., 5.]])
```

In the fig. below the random points are plotted, together with the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix with a length of the square root of their eigenvalues, like on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:GaussianScatterPCA.svg).

[image: random points with the desired properties]

Comment: Sorry, do you know how to change your code to pick only one element from this multivariate normal distribution? A pair, I mean.

Comment: The type of `res` is `np.ndarray`, which contains all the x, y pairs, and `res.shape` returns `(10000, 2)`. To get the first pair, `res[0]` returns the corresponding x, y values in another `np.ndarray`, with a shape of (2,). To get the x value of the *i*th element, type `res[I][0]`, and type `res[I][1]` for the y value.